# Preimage of a regular point for 1-periodic hamiltonian

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, symplectic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem [DELZANT]

Theorem: Let $(M,w)$ be a compact symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$ and $H$ a 1-periodic hamiltonian in $M$. If $H$ only has two critical values and one is non-degenerate(in usual sense), then $M$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{CP}^n, \lambda \omega_{FS})$ for a certain $\lambda$.

During the proof, it is supposed that the critical points are $0$ and $\lambda$ where $H(M)= [0,\lambda]$. Then, for regular value $\epsilon$ , it says that $H^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is an sphere ( $S^{2n-1}$). Why is that? I can' t understand it.

Comment: May I know which texts are you using?

Comment: Proof is from "Hamiltoniens périodiques et images convexes de l'application moment" by Thomas Delzant ( same article where he proves Delzant theorem). I don't know if there is a translation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a compact *connected* symplectic manifold. (We have to assume connectedness, otherwise any disjoint union of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$'s would work.) Let $H : M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a 1-periodic Hamiltonian and suppose that is only has two critical values; As $M$ is compact, $H$ has a minimum (say w.l.o.g. $0$) and a maximum (say $\lambda \ge 0$), so the assumption on $H$ implies that the two critical values are precisely the maximal value $\lambda > 0$ and the minimal value $0$ of $H$.

Assume that one of the two critical values is nondegenerate (w.l.o.g., possibly considering $\tilde{H} := \lambda - H$ instead, say $0$), that is, for any critical point $p \in H^{-1}(\{0\})$, the Hessian of $H$ at $p$ is nondegenerate. Put differently, the function $H : M \setminus H^{-1}(\{\lambda \}) \to [0, \lambda)$ is Morse. As $M$ is compact, it implies that $H^{-1}(\{0\})$ consists of finitely many isolated points.

With the aid of Morse lemma, one observes that given $p \in H^{-1}(\{0\})$ and a 'Morse chart' $(U, \phi : U \to \mathbb{R}^{2n})$ for $H$ about $p$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small such that the intersection of a level set $H^{-1}(\{c \})$ for $c \in (0,0 + \epsilon)$ with $U$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{2n-1}$. According to Morse theory, the topology of level sets of a Morse function changes only at critical values. It follows that $M \setminus H^{-1}(\{\lambda \})$ is diffeomorphic to $\sqcup_{p \in H^{-1}(\{0\})} B^{2n}$, where $B^{2n}$ denotes the open 2n-dimensional ball.

It seems at least intuitively plausible that 'the Morse flow' of $H$ glues each $\overline{B^{2n}}$ (or rather, its boundary) to (a connected component of) $H^{-1}(\{\lambda \})$. The gluing has to be done in such a way that we recover the *smooth* manifold $M$; It is not a trivial result, even though I guess it is intuitively plausible, that this forces each connected component $H^{-1}(\{\lambda\})$ to be glued with precisely one of the $B^{2n}$'s. As we assume $M$ to be connected, this implies that $H^{-1}(\{\lambda \})$ is connected and also that there is only one $B^{2n}$ (i.e. $H^{-1}(\{0\})$) has cardinality 1). This 'proves' the claim.

As the gluing has to be done in an equivariant way with respect to the $S^1$-action induced by $H$, the (surjective) gluing map $\partial B^{2n} = S^{2n-1} \to H^{-1}(\{\lambda \})$ has to factorize through the Hopf fibration $S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$. So $M$ would be diffeomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ by an equivalence relation which at most identifies points in the hyperplane $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$; It appears difficult (and according to the theorem, impossible) for such a (nontrivial) quotient to be smooth and symplectic (one could collapse $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ to a point, so $M$ would be the smooth manifold $S^{2n}$, but it cannot be symplectic if $n > 1$).

Comment: This proofs looks a bit different of the one I'm reading. Anyway, the thing is that $H^{-1}(\epsilon)$ being $S^{2n-1} is then consequence of "Morse lemma"? I guess the proof I'm reading admits a lot of results to be known or trivial then...

Comment: Delzant's paper is not easy to read. I had the impression that what he considered as trivial or folklore, and what wasn't, was kind of different of my own perspective... Anyway, yes, the Morse lemma tells you exactly how a Morse function looks like near its critical points (and Théorème 1.1 in Delzant's paper is exactly a Hamiltonian and Morse-Bott version of this lemma). Then the gradient flow allows to extend this local knowledge to a somewhat 'global' one, as long as you don't reach another critical value. Théorème 1.1 allows you to rigorously express the intuition in my last 2 paragraphs.